# Scala Spark Dataframe: how to explode an array of Int and array of struct at the same time

Tags: sql, arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala/Spark and I'm trying to make explode a dataframe that has an array column and array of struct column so that I end up with no arrays and no struct.

Here's an example

```
case class Area(start_time: String, end_time: String, area: String)

val df = Seq((
  "1", Seq(4,5,6), 
  Seq(Area("07:00", "07:30", "70"), Area("08:00", "08:30", "80"), Area("09:00", "09:30", "90"))
)).toDF("id", "before", "after")
df.printSchema
df.show
```

`df` has the following schema

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- before: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- after: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- end_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- area: string (nullable = true)
```

and the data looks like

```
+---+---------+--------------------+
| id|   before|               after|
+---+---------+--------------------+
|  1|[4, 5, 6]|[[07:00, 07:30, 7...|
+---+---------+--------------------+
```

How do I explode the dataframe so I get the following schema

```
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- before: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- after_start_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- after_end_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- after_area: string (nullable = true)
```

The resulting data should have 3 rows and 5 columns

```
+---+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
| id|   before|    after_start_time|    after_start_time|    area|
+---+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|  1|        4|               07:00|               07:30|      70|
|  1|        5|               08:00|               08:30|      80|
|  1|        6|               09:00|               09:30|      90|
+---+---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

I'm using spark 2.3.0 (`arrays_zip` is not available). And the only solutions I can find is either for exploding two Arrays of String or one Array of struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `arrays_zip` to combine two arrays, then `explode` to explode array columns & use `as` to rename required columns.

As `arrays_zip` is not available in `spark 2.3`. Created UDF to perform same operation.

```
val arrays_zip = udf((before:Seq[Int],after: Seq[Area]) => before.zip(after))
```

Execution time with built in (spark 2.4.2) `arrays_zip`     - Time taken: `1146 ms`

Execution time with `arrays_zip` UDF                    - Time taken: `1165 ms`

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |before   |after                                                       |
+---+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[4, 5, 6]|[[07:00, 07:30, 70], [08:00, 08:30, 80], [09:00, 09:30, 90]]|
+---+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+


scala> 
df
.select(
    $"id",
    explode(
        arrays_zip($"before",$"after")
        .cast("array<struct<before:int,after:struct<start_time:string,end_time:string,area:string>>>")
    ).as("before_after")
)
.select(
    $"id",
    $"before_after.before".as("before"),
    $"before_after.after.start_time".as("after_start_time"),
    $"before_after.after.end_time".as("after_end_time"),
    $"before_after.after.area"
)
.printSchema

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- before: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- after_start_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- after_end_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- area: string (nullable = true)
```

**Output**

```
scala> 

df
.select(
    $"id",
    explode(
        arrays_zip($"before",$"after")
        .cast("array<struct<before:int,after:struct<start_time:string,end_time:string,area:string>>>")
    ).as("before_after")
)
.select(
    $"id",
    $"before_after.before".as("before"),
    $"before_after.after.start_time".as("after_start_time"),
    $"before_after.after.end_time".as("after_end_time"),
    $"before_after.after.area"
)
.show(false)

+---+------+----------------+--------------+----+
|id |before|after_start_time|after_end_time|area|
+---+------+----------------+--------------+----+
|1  |4     |07:00           |07:30         |70  |
|1  |5     |08:00           |08:30         |80  |
|1  |6     |09:00           |09:30         |90  |
+---+------+----------------+--------------+----+
```

Comment: I can't use `arrays_zip` because I'm using spark 2.3.0. It's only available for spark 2.4.0+

Comment: ```arrays_zip``` is not available in ```spark 2.3``` version & created udf ```arrays_zip``` . now check

Comment: the schema for `case class Area` is actually a lot more complicated than what I gave in the example. Is there anyway I can specify the case class by extrapolating the schema from the dataframe? For example, something like `df.select($"after").schema`

Comment: are you asking about inside udf ```Area```  ?

Comment: yes, so the schema for `Area` is way more complicated than `case class Area(start_time: String, end_time: String, area: String)`. But it seems that I have to specify it because it's used in `after: Seq[Area]`. Is there any way I can specify the structure of `Area` without writing it out by hand? The schema of `Area` is actually multiple layers of Arrays

Comment: I think no, I will check if i get any other options will update solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for something like `val areaSchema = df.select($"area").schema`, `val arrays_zip = udf((before:Seq[Int],after: areaSchema) => before.zip(after))`

Comment: passing schema of type ```StructType``` to ```udf``` is not possible as far as i know.. how are you creating dataframe for area data??

Comment: I'm importing the data from somewhere else so it comes with a schema

Comment: do you want only one element or all elements from array of struct ??

Comment: There's only one element within `Area` I'm interested in, but it's very nested. So `Area` looks like `[[col1, col2, ..., colOfInterest, ..colN]]`. I need to get to `colOfInterest`. Basically, `Area` is an array of struct, and within the struct there are many variables, I'm only interested in one `colOfInterest`, which an array

Comment: why don't you use flatten all columns if you don't know schema. do you want flatten all columns ??

Comment: I know the schema, just writing it out by hand into a case class would take hours. Would flatten all the columns allow me to match up `colOfInterest` with the `before` array?

Comment: yes, you can match. only problem flattening all columns is you will get lot of duplicates .. for example before is any array has 3 values & after is an array has 3 values .. final rows you will get 9 rows.

Answer (score 0):

To handle some complex struct you can do,

1. Declare two beans Area(input) and Area2(output)
2. Map row to Area2 bean

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema

import scala.collection.mutable

object ExplodeTwoArrays {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = Seq((
      "1", Seq(4, 5, 6),
      Seq(Area("07:00", "07:30", "70"), Area("08:00", "08:30", "80"), Area("09:00", "09:30", "90"))
    )).toDF("id", "before", "after")
    val outDf = df.map(row=> {
      val id = row.getString(0)
      val beforeArray : Seq[Int]= row.getSeq[Int](1)
      val afterArray : mutable.WrappedArray[Area2] =
        row.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema]](2) // Need to map Array(Struct) to the something compatible
          .zipWithIndex   // Require to iterate with indices
          .map{ case(element,i) => {
          Area2(element.getAs[String]("start_time"),
            element.getAs[String]("end_time"),
            element.getAs[String]("area"),
            beforeArray(i))
        }}
      (id,afterArray)   // Return row(id,Array(Area2(...)))
    }).toDF("id","after")

    outDf.printSchema()

    outDf.show()

  }

}

case class Area(start_time: String, end_time: String, area: String)

case class Area2(start_time: String, end_time: String, area: String, before: Int)
```

Comment: So the schema of Area is very nested, but I'm only interested in one column within the nested array. Something like `[[ ..., variableOfInterest, ...]]`. How would I go about referring to `variableOfInterest`, when it's nested within `Array[Struct[...]]`?

Comment: Just call `element.getAs[String]("variableOfInterest")` if its of String type in the map block @Amazonian

Comment: Is there a way I can do that while having it match with the order of the `before` array?

Comment: you mean the order of before and after array might be different and you need to use `variableOfInterest` of to identify the position for after array? @Amazonian

Comment: no, I meant the `before` array and `after` array have the same number of elements and they correspond to each other. Actually, if I explode one array at a time, would the order of the array be preserved?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out: I can explode each array indiviudally using `posexplode_outer` and then join the two dataframes by `id` and `pos = position of element in the array`. Would that work?